# \Sexpr shows only one value from a vector with two elements in sweave

Tags: r, sweave

I can't get the two elements of the vector using:

```
<<>>=
z=c(1,2)
@

\Sexpr{z}
```

I have googled a lot but don't understand why I get just the first element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the documented behavior.  From Sweave manual (the emphasis is mine):

> There is limited support for using the values of R objects in text
>   chunks. Any occurrence of \Sexpr{expr } is replaced by the string
>   resulting from coercing the value of the expression expr to a
>   character vector; *only the first element of this vector is used*. E.g.,
>   3 will be replaced by the string '3' (without any quotes).

Use `[\Sexpr{paste(z, collapse=", ")}]`.  `paste` will collapse your vector into a char string, which is output by `\Sexpr`, so the result is `[1, 2]`